# Selecting value between two dates

Tags: excel, vba

Here i am trying to calcualte grand total from column H when column E which is date range has date between two dates ( dtst and dtet). For some reason its not working result coming 0. any help here ?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Compare()

Dim NumberOfValues As Long
Dim value3, value4, value5 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim dtst, dtet As Date

dtst = CDate(3 / 1 / 2022)
dtet = CDate(6 / 30 / 2022)

NumberOfValues = Sheets("backuplist_PPBAMR301P_2021-12-2").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
value3 = 0
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To NumberOfValues

    If Range("C" & i).Value <> "*REPLICATE*" Then
            If CDate(Range("E" & i).Value) >= dtst And CDate(Range("E" & i).Value) <= dtet Then
                 If Range("M" & i).Value = 1 Or Range("M" & i).Value = 0 Then
                        value3 = value3 + Range("H" & i).Value
            End If
                 End If
                 
                 
    End If

Next
value4 = value3 / 1024
value5 = value4 / 1024
Range("Z" & 8).Value = value3
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you debug your code to see if what your expecting is happening? Seems you could also do this with `SUMIFS`

Comment: `Debug.Print Format(CDate(3/1/2022),"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")` might show you the issue.  `CDate("3/1/2022")` is probably what you want there.

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/10/07/excel-sumifs-date-range-between-two-dates/#sumif-another-criteria

Comment: now tried using CDate("3/1/2022") code "If CDate(Range("E" & i).Value) >= dtst And CDate(Range("E" & i).Value) <= dtet " giving type mismatch error.